# Poisson bracket with the symplectic form

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, poisson-geometry

Consider the following extract from a text:

[image]

I can't seem to varify the second equality in the definition. Maybe the author meant to write $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}})^T J \frac{\partial g}{\partial \mathbf x}$ ?

If someone could clarify this for me I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: That is correct, you should take the tranpose.

Comment: Great, thanks! Feel free to post this an answer.

Comment: If you feel that a comment has answered your question, or if you have found an answer yourself, you can post your own answer! If you do not wish to receive reputation (i.e. you just want to take the question off the list of unanswered questions), you can tick the "Community Wiki" box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a transposition missing. The definition should say
$$
\{f,g\}:=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\right)^T J \frac{\partial g}{\partial \mathbf x}.
$$